# Copying an MySQL/Debian8 Database to a different platform

Tags: php, mysql, import, debian

I found variations on how to make copies of a DB, and fill in tables, within the same platform, but I want to port to a different platform.

I tried Archiving the folder with the same name as my DB form /var/lib/mysql, changing the folder name, then extracting back to /var/lib/mysql.

When I fired up phpMyAdmin, it showed the new database name, but no tables.

I expect the same thing to happen when I extract on the new platform, but there I won't be able to use the Insert from a local copy.

What directories and/or files does MySQL on Debian8 need to be tweaked to let the tables show?

Comment: You should use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-and-recovery.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  mysqldump said Dump Completed, but I don't see where it was stored.  I'm interested in doing a secure ftp "put" to another platform.

Comment: Redirect its output to a file - as shown in the [examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-examples)

Comment: Thanks for the help